# How to override PHP session read from files?

Tags: php, session, centos, upgrade, php-7.4

For work I'm upgrading a large custom PHP program from PHP v5.6 to 7.4, and I'm nearing the end but keep seeing a session read warning on session-start and after logging out (probably because a new session is generated for the loading of the consequent login page).

```
Warning session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /var/lib/php/session)
```

Let me be clear, before you read any further.  **The program does not store session data in files.**  The issue I'm trying to work through is not a file-permissions issue.
It's my understanding that you can use PHP's built-in session handling, referring to its .ini configs, `session.save_handler` and `session.save_path`, or override them by implementing the `session_set_save_handler()` function.  This application is using the 2nd option, and implements its own MemCached session handling using the callable functions passed into the `session_set_save_handler()` function, and this seems to be working perfectly well, except for the above warning.

The .ini configs have been set at different times like these, below, which result in different "local values" and "master values" in the php-info page.

```
session.save_handler = "files"
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"

session.save_handler=
session.save_path=

session.save_handler = "custom_handler"
session.save_path = "/"

# commented out
;session.save_handler = "files"
;session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"
```

However, they all still allow for this warning-error to be emitted, just with a different file path to where the session fails to read data from (which is irrelevant in this case because the application is not writing session data there).

### UPDATE:

The 'read' function handler:

```
public function read($sessionId)
{
    if(isset($GLOBALS['sess']))
    {
        return $GLOBALS['sess'];
    }

    $sessionKey = self::formatSessionKey($sessionId);

    $data = SV_GETMEMCACHED()->get($sessionKey);

    $GLOBALS['sess'] = $data;
    $GLOBALS['sess_hash'] = md5($data);

    return $data ?: '';
}
```

</update>

I have some questions which haven't been addressed by the PHP documentation, nor my research.

1stly, does `session_set_save_handler()` override the `save_handler` and `save_path` configs, or do they work in tandem somehow? (the latter seems to be the case)
Can someone please describe the dynamic between these different configuration options?  (I understand them both on a basic level, but I obviously do not know how they interplay since I'm getting this warning while implementing our own handler functions.)

2ndly, when we implement the 'read' functionality for the `session_set_save_handler()`, we're instructed to either return the session data, or an empty string.  Does returning an empty string prompt PHP to attempt to read session data by the .ini configured method?  If so, can I suppress that or configure PHP to NOT do this, to not use alternate read-sources for session data?

3rdly, is executing `session_set_save_handler()` one time, at the onset of the program sufficient for the entire script run?  My predecessor had it being called a number of other times, e.g. when a session was destroyed.  Are there any events or actions which negate or bypass or void what is set from the first execution of `session_set_save_handler()`?  Is there a context/scope consideration where it's called from?  Or, is it sufficient to merely call/set it prior to `session_start()`?

Thanks for any insights or questions that may lead to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Through the help of a consultant, I finally made the connection that repeated session accesses within the same request are cached internally in the $GLOBALS array (which probably should have been obvious), and this has a shortcut return statement that's allowing unwanted values.

The consultant recommended restructuring the code to have just one return point, which is fair enough, and may have prevented this blindspot/brainfart.

And I did restructure, like this.

```
public function read($sessionId)
{
    if(!array_key_exists('sess', $GLOBALS))
    {
        $sessionKey = self::formatSessionKey($sessionId);

        $GLOBALS['sess'] = GETMEMCACHED()->get($sessionKey);
    }
    
    // SESSION READS _MUST_ RETURN A VALID SESSION STRING, OR AN EMPTY STRING
    $sessionData = $GLOBALS['sess'] ?: '';

    $GLOBALS['sess_hash'] = md5($sessionData);

    return $sessionData;
}
```